# Database design for surveys in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm trying to design an app where users take a new survey everyday (that's not the main part of app but it's an important part). I've never designed a database before so what I'm trying to do might not make any sense.

I'm using MySQL and I have a table for user information (user_id, name, password, etc). What I plan on doing is making a new table for each new survey and linking it with the user_id. So basically, I would have one table having a relationship with hundreds of other tables.

Is that how it would work? I thought about adding a column to the user table for every survey but I read that it's bad design to add columns often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make one table for all surveys. Don't make a new table for each survey.

Also, make sure you hash and salt your passwords with bcrypt.